# Dynamically created string allocated on heap or stack - C

Tags: c++, c, memory, allocation

## Context

I was experimenting with getting C strings in C++ without allocating memory on the heap and came across this in testing:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* get_empty_c_string(size_t length) {
    char buffer[length];
    char *string = buffer;

    for (size_t i = 0; i ^ length; i++) *(string + i) = '\0';

    return string;
}

int main(void) {
    char *string = get_empty_c_string(20u); // Allocated on heap?
                                            // or stack?
    return 0;
}
```

---

## Question

Is the C string returned allocated on heap or stack?

As far as I know:

- Heap allocation occurs with the `calloc`, `malloc` & `realloc` C standard functions or `new` & `new[]` C++ keywords.
- Stack allocation in most other cases.

Comment: `char buffer[length];` -- This is not valid C++.

Comment: [Variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#C99) is valid only in C, not C++ as mentioned above.

Comment: And even if we are assuming that variable-length array such as this are valid in C++ or that the code is C, you are returning a pointer to stack-allocated memory that will be invalid as soon as the function returns. `string` is not usable in `main`.

Comment: I ran this code on GCC with all warning flags set using `-Wall` and this was not mentioned...

Comment: *`i < length`. Sorry `i ^ length` is my personal style of code.

Comment: @Lapys GCC supports VLAs as compiler extension by default. In order for GCC to behave standard-conform, you need to add the `-pedantic-errors` flag.

Comment: Ah, understood. I re-compiled with the `-pedantic-errors` flag and it did give an error. Thanks for helping out @openingnow and @walnut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array `buffer` is a **variable length array** (VLA), meaning its size is determined at runtime.  As a variable local to a function is resides on the stack.  The pointer `string` then points to that array, and that pointer is returned.  And because the returned pointer points to a local stack variable which goes out of scope, attempting to use that pointer will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Also, note that VLAs are a C only feature.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in standard C++ to obtain runtime-sized memory of automatic storage duration (which usually maps to stack memory).

Therefore a proper string of any length cannot be obtained on the stack. You can only allocate a buffer with a maximal size and use strings up to that length in the program. (Something similar is usually done by `std::string` as so-called *short string optimization*.)

Furthermore, you cannot return pointers or references to variables with automatic storage duration from a function. When the function returns the variables are destroyed and the pointer/reference becomes invalid. You can only ever use the stack-allocation until the function returns. You can however return the variable by-value.

Comment: <i>Short string optimization</i>? Sounds like another interesting thing to learn

Answer (score 0):

As @PaulMcKenzie points out, your implementation of `get_empty_c_string()` would fail to compile: In essence, arrays as temporary/instance variables of a function need to have a static size defined for them prior to compile time. This is because that volume of memory is *pushed onto the stack* at function invocation.

I can see that you're trying to have dynamic memory allocation as part of the function itself, which is why you need such heap-allocators.

Comment: Hmm, understood.
Without the `-pedantic-errors` flags though, the code compiles freely; As @walnut says, GCC supports VLAs as compiler extensions by default apparently